# Keras ValueError: Could not pack sequence. Structure had X atoms, but flat_sequence had Y items

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When saving the Keras model, I am getting this error

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/haseeb/pss-lrev-fix/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/haseeb/pss-lrev-fix/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 685, in _pack_sequence_as
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not pack sequence. Structure had 2 atoms, but flat_sequence had 0 items.  Structure: [<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'b4463af4e8b211eda53b9d14cf2ceb12input_3')>, <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'b4463af5e8b211eda53b9d14cf2ceb12pp_input_2')>], flat_sequence: [].
```

Before this, the model was unable to save because of the duplicated model, so I changed the model layer names with uuid values to avoid that problem for a while; however, I am getting this error after that.

I tried deleting `None` and `[]` layers with

```py
if layer.output_shape == None or layer.output_shape[1] == []:
    layer.pop()
```

But upon saving, I am getting the same error.